# Android - Idle Timeout to Auto Launch an Application

Tags: android, timeout, autostart

Does Anyone know how to start in Android specific app after idle timeout(inactive mode). 
I would like to always launch my app when android device switches from inactive to active mode.
Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have an "idle timeout" concept, other than the screen turning off or the device switching to show a daydream.

Comment: What I have meant by my question is to detect in some way "active mode of the screen"- it is not frozen and black and then automatically launch "my app". So, whenever screen switch from inactive to active my app is launched. I have already seen that feature in one app

Comment: @user2692429: "whenever screen switch from inactive to active my app is launched" -- sorry, but I have no idea what you mean by "inactive" and "active" in this context.